# Definition of Wave map on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, tangent-bundle, co-tangent-space

Let $u: V \rightarrow M$, where $(V,g)$ is a Lorentzian manifold and $(M,h)$ is a Riemannian manifold.

The wave equation is defined as $g. \nabla^2 u$.

As far as I see, $\nabla^2 u \in \Gamma(T^{*}V \otimes T^{*}V \otimes TM)$, since $\nabla_{\partial_{\alpha}} u= \partial_{\alpha} u \in \Gamma(T^{*}V \otimes TM)$. Is that correct?

But then, how can you apply $g$ on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mapping is a *harmonic* map, if the mapping $u$ satisifes $g \cdot \nabla^2 u=0$ then in local coordinates
\begin{align}
g^{\alpha \beta}\nabla_\alpha \partial_{\beta}u^A &= g^{\alpha \beta}(\partial^2_{\alpha \beta}u^A - \Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha \beta}\partial_{\lambda} u^A+ \Gamma^A_{BC}\partial_{\alpha}u^B \partial_{\beta}u^C)\\
&=0
\end{align}
And this is how you apply $g$, as you say.